# Need Guidance on Implementing In-App Billing and Server Verification in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I'm relatively new to in-app billing and payments on Android, specifically dealing with Google's services. I've been following the documentation provided by Google here, but I'm encountering challenges in implementing server-side verification for subscriptions.

What I've done so far:

1. I've closely followed the steps outlined in the official
   documentation.
2. I'm facing difficulties verifying subscriptions on the back-end.
3. During testing, I'm unable to retrieve meaningful logs.
4. Testing is limited to internal testing, and I'm unable to find
   adequate tutorials that align with the new version (V3) or are
   easily comprehensible.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding the implementation details and server-side verification process, particularly in Java.

Any guidance, corrections, or up-to-date tutorials would be greatly appreciated. I'm also interested in learning how to effectively test the application without the restriction of internal testing only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android In-App Billing Library v4+**

A simple implementation of the Android In-App Billing API.

**Getting Started**

● Add the dependency in your app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.moisoni97:google-inapp-billing:1.0.5'
}
```

● Create an instance of BillingConnector class. Constructor will take 2 parameters:

```
 ● Context
 ● License key from *Play Console*
```

```
billingConnector = new BillingConnector(this, "license_key")
                .setConsumableIds(consumableIds)
                .setNonConsumableIds(nonConsumableIds)
                .setSubscriptionIds(subscriptionIds)
                .autoAcknowledge()
                .autoConsume()
                .enableLogging()
                .connect();
```

More Info. on Github :- https://github.com/Mahadev-code/Android-inApp-Billing